# RNetLogo activate switch

Tags: r, netlogo

I'm actually using the package RNetLogo for R with a NetLogo model that uses many switches.
Infortunaly, I didn't find how to activate these switches in R. I can't find this information on internet. I tried with the commande "NLCommand" but it didn't work...

I hope someone know how to do. 
Otherwise I'll change my NetLogo code..

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `NLCommand("set myswitch true")` should do the trick.
Otherwise please provide a small example of your code.